# Javascript Alternative to Iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am an admin on an online roleplaying game, and we recently made the transition from some sort of Frankencode to javascript. While I have the basics down, there is a problem I have encountered that I am not sure how to fix.

We have macros on the game, where you can move multiple rooms by typing the direction with a space, a semi-colon, and another space between directions. I've created an atlas that has a long list of macros to help the players of the game move around faster and more efficiently. My main problem is, everything worked with the Frankencode, but Javascript is not recognizing the iframe in my new code.

I would really like an alternative to iframes where I don't have to rely on an outside website for this script, but my journey into that hopeful line of thought just led to a bunch of bright red, angry errors and the command breaking. I substituted the iframe for a contentedtable and the game just was not having it!

Below is my code. Keep in mind that everything works except the iframe.

Thanks in advance! :)

```html
var macaroni = "<center><img src=http://i188.photobucket.com/albums/z46/roseblossomsnapdragon/items/atlas.jpg><BR><image src= http://i188.photobucket.com/albums/z46/roseblossomsnapdragon/amazingatlas-1.jpg~original><BR/> <b><font color=blue><u><b>IF ANY OF THESE ARE BROKEN, INFORM VICTORIA.</font></u></b></b><BR> <table border=0> <tr> <td Valign=top bgcolor=white> <IFRAME name=inlineframe src=http://karchanhelp.webs.com/other%20stuff/otherotherstuff/macaroni.htm width=550 height=400 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 frameborder=0 scrolling=auto></IFRAME></td> <td Valign=top bgcolor=white><form method=post action=> <textarea name=comments cols=80 rows=21> Copy and paste here to build longer macros. </textarea> </form></td> </tr> </table><P> </center>";
var macaroons = "<center><img src=http://i188.photobucket.com/albums/z46/roseblossomsnapdragon/items/atlas.jpg><BR><image src= http://i188.photobucket.com/albums/z46/roseblossomsnapdragon/amazingatlas-1.jpg~original><BR/> <b><font color=blue><u><b>IF ANY OF THESE ARE BROKEN, INFORM VICTORIA.</font></u></b></b><BR> <table border=0> <tr> <td Valign=top bgcolor=white> <IFRAME name=inlineframe src=http://karchanhelp.webs.com/other%20stuff/otherotherstuff/macaroni.htm width=550 height=400 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 frameborder=0 scrolling=auto></IFRAME></td> <td Valign=top bgcolor=white><form method=post action=> <textarea name=comments cols=80 rows=21> Copy and paste here to build longer macros. </textarea> </form></td> </tr> </table><P> </center>";

function command(person, totalcommand) {
if (person.isAttribute("macaroons"))
{
person.personal(macaroons);
person.sendMessage("%SNAME begin%VERB2 studying an atlas out of nowhere.<BR>");
return;
}
person.personal(macaroni);
person.sendMessage("%SNAME begin%VERB2 studying an atlas out of nowhere.<BR>");
return;
}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem?  You say it's something to do with an iframe and you show some HTML for an iframe, but you don't really explain exactly what the javascript problem is.  What do you mean "javascript not recognizing the iframe"?

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to iframes is AJAX(Asynchronos Javascript and XML) which lets you load pages and data from a server and you can handle the results for that and insert the response back into your page.

The best pages for learning about Javascript are from the Mozilla Developer Network and [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) especially will help you learn more about ajax.

However there are libraries you can download, such as jQuery that help simplify a lot of tasks including loading and storing html and more.

If you need to store a website you can do the following:

**Include jQuery in the HEAD:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Create a div(or other container for storing) with any id you want(should be unique):**

```
<div id="loadingArea"></div>
```

**Include a script at either the end of the page or end of the head to ensure that jQuery has loaded**

```
<script>
   $(document).ready( //Will run the following function when the html document is ready
        function() {
           var url = "http://karchanhelp.webs.com/other%20stuff/otherotherstuff/macaroni.htm"; //Load the page you want.
           var portion = "body >" //select the portion of the page you need to eliminate duplicate html, head, and body tags
                                  //This is a jQuery selector similar to css meaning select all children (>) of body

           //Here we tell jQuery to select the element with id(#) loadingArea and load the
           //portion of the url.
           $('#loadingArea').load(url+" "+portion);
        }
   ); //End of ready call
</script>
```